# How to configure an object in Palantir Foundry to add a tab

Tags: palantir-foundry

I'd like to add another tab to the object view of my object that has a few specific properties.  Is there a way I can configure this? Or do I need to link to a different object to get another tab?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have edit permissions on the object view, you can add a tab with the steps below.

1. Edit the object view.
   [image]
2. Add a new tab.
   [image]